# How to limit the number of message that an Arduino sends to a phone without terminating it

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, sensors, gsm

I just stayed on `delay()` since that is the only thing I know but the thing is `delay()` cannot be interrupted. What I'm trying to achieve with this code is:

1. When the soilSensor detects moisture it would send a text message to a number only ONCE without terminating the program even if in the next loop the soilSensor is still detecting moisture.
2. The soilSensor's delay is `delay(60000)` and we would still wait for while to finish the delay but what if in the middle of the soilSensor's `delay(60000)` there is a movement for just about 5 seconds? What to do so that the tiltSensor can overlap the soilSensor's delay and sends a message to a number?

I want this program to run forever. Please help me! I needed this ASAP!

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);
int led=22;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM900.begin(19200);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  delay(1000); 
}

void sendSMS1()
{
  SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+************\"");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Water Detected");
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("Water Detected"); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println((char)26); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println();
  delay(100); 
}


void sendSMS2()
{
  SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+************\"");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Movement Detected");
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("Movement Detected"); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println((char)26); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println();
  delay(100);  
}


void loop()
{    
  int soilSensor = analogRead(A0);
  int tiltSensor = analogRead(A1);

  if(soilSensor >= 10)
  {
    digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
    Serial.println(soilSensor);
    sendSMS1();
    delay(60000);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(22, LOW);
    delay(60000); 
  } 

  if (tiltSensor >= 100)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    Serial.println(tiltSensor);
    sendSMS2();
    delay(60000);
  }
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    Serial.println(tiltSensor);
    delay(60000);
  }
}
```

Comment: [BlinkWithoutDelay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) is good reference material for solving this issue.

Comment: If *you* were the Arduino, how would *you* go about solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You use millis() to keep track of time and also prevent blocking. Replicating your program logic:

```
long soil_timer = 0;
long tilt_timer = 0;
char soil_flag = 1;
char tilt_flag = 1;

void loop() { 
    int soilSensor = analogRead(A0); 
    int tiltSensor = analogRead(A1); 

  if (soil_flag == 1) {
    if (soilSensor >= 10) { 
      digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
      Serial.println(soilSensor);
      sendSMS1(); 
    }
   else { 
      digitalWrite(22, LOW);
    }
    soil_timer = millis();
    soil_flag = 0;
  }

  if (tilt_flag == 1) {
    if (tiltSensor >= 100) { 
       digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
       Serial.println(tiltSensor);
       sendSMS2();
    } 
    else { 
       digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
       Serial.println(tiltSensor);
    } 
    tilt_flag = 0;
    tilt_timer = millis();
  }
  if (millis() - soil_timer >= 60000){
     soil_flag = 1;
  }
  if (millis() - tilt_timer >= 60000){
     tilt_flag = 1;
  }
}
```